# Does Perl 6 have a built-in tool to make a deep copy of a nested data structure?

Tags: deep-copy, raku

Does Perl 6 have a built-in tool to make a deep copy of a nested data structure?

Added example:

```
my %hash_A = (
    a => {
        aa => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
        bb => { aaa => 1, bbb => 2 },
    },
);


my %hash_B = %hash_A;
#my %hash_B = %hash_A.clone; # same result

%hash_B<a><aa>[2] = 735;

say %hash_A<a><aa>[2]; # says "735" but would like get "3"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
my %A = (
    a => {
        aa => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
        bb => { aaa => 1, bbb => 2 },
    },
);

my %B = %A.deepmap(-> $c is copy {$c}); # make sure we get a new container instead of cloning the value

dd %A;
dd %B;

%B<a><aa>[2] = 735;

dd %A;
dd %B;
```

Use `.clone` and `.deepmap` to request a copy/deep-copy of a data-structure. But don't bet on it. Any object can define its own `.clone` method and do whatever it wants with it. If you must mutate and therefore must clone, make sure you test your program with large datasets. Bad algorithms can render a program virtually useless in production use.

Comment: It might be nice to *show* how to use `deepmap` with clone

Comment: The binding should not be needed. There seams to be a bug somewhere.

Comment: ENOBUG. deepmap in conjunction with clone will do as asked. see: http://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-07-26#i_12912861

Answer (score 3):

The dirty way:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl6

use v6;
use MONKEY-SEE-NO-EVAL;

my %hash_A = (
    a => {
        aa => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
        bb => { aaa => 1, bbb => 2 },
    },
);


my %hash_B;
EVAL '%hash_B = (' ~ %hash_A.perl ~ ' )';

%hash_B<a><aa>[2] = 735;

say %hash_A;
say %hash_B;
```

which gives you:

```
$ perl6 test.p6
{a => {aa => [1 2 3 4 5], bb => {aaa => 1, bbb => 2}}}
{a => {aa => [1 2 735 4 5], bb => {aaa => 1, bbb => 2}}}
```

If you eval input from external source, always remember to check it first. Anyway, using [EVAL](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/EVAL) is dangerous and should be avoided.