# perl6 array assignment: pointer or copy?

Tags: arrays, pointers, clone, variable-assignment, raku

In perl6, I want to assign an array to another array and have the resulting array be distinct entity, but it seems neither direct assignment nor cloning can do what I want. Is there a way to copy array over with one expression instead of writing a loop routine?

```
To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> my @a=<a b c d e>
[a b c d e]
> my @b = <1 2 3 4 5 6 7>
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
> my @c = @a
[a b c d e]
> @c[3]
d
> @c[3]=3;
3
> @c
[a b c 3 e]
> @a
[a b c d e]
> @c === @a
False
> @c == @a
True          # this is unexpected, @c and @a should be different, right?
> my @x=@a.clone
[a b c d e]
> @x[3]=3
3
> @x
[a b c 3 e]
> @x === @a
False
> @x == @a
True         # unexpected, @x and @a should be distinct things, right?
>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were unlucky to not compare with @b that might have helped you figure it out :)

`==` is numeric comparison, so when you asked for a list to be compared as a number it picked the number of elements as a representation. Operators in Perl 5 or 6 coerce the types involved. If you want to test if the elements of the array are the same try the `eqv` operator.

Comparing lengths of arrays, so the following is true:

```
@a == @c == @x == 5
```

Try:

```
my @a = <a b c d e>;
my @b = <1 2 3 4 5>;
@a eqv @b;
```

You might want to check out some of the docs around these operators. The smart match `~~` operator is probably more what you were expecting with `==`.

https://docs.perl6.org/routine/$EQUALS_SIGN$EQUALS_SIGN
https://docs.perl6.org/routine/$TILDE$TILDE

Comment: Thank you Matt !! So, when I assign one array to another, the contents are copied and they are distinct arrays, right?

Comment: Yes and no. You get a shallow copy for scalar types. So things that are container like so say another array you only get a new container pointing to the same list. So an example where it's maybe not what you expect: `my @a = [1,[2,3]]; my @b = @a; @b[1][0] = 4;` This will change 2 to be 4 in @a too!

Comment: If you want a deep copy then this has been answered previously here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582873/does-perl-6-have-a-built-in-tool-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-a-nested-data-structure